# Não consigo clonar repositório com git bash

Tags: git, github, bash

Gostaria de saber por que não consigo clonar um repositório público do Github com o git bash. Dou o comando `git clone` mais o ssh ou o https, 
 mas dá a seguinte mensagem:

> Permission denied (publickey).
>     fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>     and the repository exists.

Comment: Você configurou uma chave SSH?

Comment: Não configurei não @LINQ

Comment: Como é o início da URL que você está usando pra clonar o projeto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se o repositório for público e estiver dando esse problema, você pode usar a URL HTTPS para fazer o clone.

Ao invés de usar

```
git clone git@github.com:phplegends/sysv.git
```

use

```
git clone https://github.com/phplegends/sysv.git
```

Geralmente quando se usa a url `ssh`, você precisa de configurar a chave. Já no caso do HTTPS, não é necessário.

Veja abaixo.

[image: Selecionar a url HTTPS no GITHUB]

Basta clicar no botão "Use HTTP" e copiar a url. Em seguida, use o comando `git clone`.

**Observações**: No Github, quando se usa a url HTTPS do repositório, para o caso do `git clone`, `git pull` e afins, não são necessários a utilização de senha. Mas para comando de envio de dados, como `git push`, você precisa digitar se autenticar.

Answer (score 2):

Para quem não está conseguindo nem com `ssh` ou `https`, o próprio site do Github disponibiliza a ajuda, é só procurarem no guia sobre `clone` e vão achar os comandos para serem feitos no git. Vou deixar os comandos prontos aí, qualquer dúvida acessem o o guia do Github.

Estes comandos devem ser feitos no terminal do Git.
Para testar se o SSH na porta HTTPS é possível, execute este comando SSH:

```
$ ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
```

> Olá username! Você conseguiu se autenticar, mas o GitHub não
>   fornece acesso shell.
>   Se deu certo, ótimo! Caso contrário, siga nosso guia para solução de problemas.

**Habilitar conexões SSH por HTTPS**

Se você conseguir fazer SSH no git@ssh.github.com na porta 443, substitua as configurações SSH para forçar qualquer conexão ao GitHub a ser executada nesse servidor e nessa porta.

Para definir isso na configuração SSH, edite o arquivo em `~/.ssh/config` e adicione esta seção:

```
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

Para testar se funciona, conecte-se mais uma vez ao GitHub:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
```

> Olá username! Você conseguiu se autenticar, mas o GitHub não fornece acesso shell.

Pronto, excute esses comandos e com certeza irá dá certo.

Answer (score -1):

**É preciso gerar e adicionar uma chave SSH na sua conta do GitHub**

Abra seu terminal e digite o comando abaixo. Ele cria uma nova chave SSH, usando o seu email como rótulo.
É preciso que o e-mail informado seja o mesmo que você utilizou para criar a sua conta no GitHub

**ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "seuemail@gmail.com"**

Durante o processo irá aparecer escrito no terminal Enter a file in which to save the key , quando isso acontecer pressione **Enter** para aceitar a localização padrão **/home/you/.ssh/id_rsa** .

Adicionando sua chave SSH ao ssh-agent
Primeiro você deve iniciar o ssh-agent em background:

**eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"**

Agora você deve adicionar sua chave privada SSH ao ssh-agent . Para isso execute o comando abaixo no terminal:

**ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa**

execute o comando abaixo e copie manualmente a saída do terminal.

**cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub**

Adicionando a chave SSH na sua conta do GitHub
execute o comando abaixo e copie manualmente a saída do terminal.
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

No canto superior direito do GitHub , clique na sua foto de perfil e clique em Settings ;
Na barra lateral esquerda, clique em SSH and GPG keys ;
Clique em New SSH key ou Add SSH key ;
No campo Título , adicione um descrição para a nova chave;
Cole sua chave dentro do campo Key ;

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).